# PCduinoV2 use Python

Tags: python

I try to test python code to PCduino V2 with MAX7219. To let 4-digit 7 segment present a counter number using SPI communication.

I connect wire from MAX7219 to PCduino:

cs to pin 10(digital I/O) 
clk to pin 13(clk)
Din to pin 11(MOSI)

This below is a source code.

```
import spi
import time
import gpio

cspin = "gpio10"

def maxsend(address, value):
    gpio.digitalWrite(cspin, gpio.LOW)
    spi.transfer(address)
    spi.transfer(value)
    gpio.digitalWrite(cspin, gpio.HIGH)

def setup():
    gpio.pinMode("gpio13", gpio.OUTPUT)
    gpio.pinMode("gpio11", gpio.OUTPUT)
    gpio.pinMode(cspin, gpio.OUTPUT)
    gpio.digitalWrite(cspin, gpio.HIGH)
    spi.openSPI(speed=1000000, mode=0)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    maxsend(0x0B, 0x06)
    maxsend(0x09, 0xFF)
    maxsend(0x0A, 0xFF)
    maxsend(0x0C, 0x01)
    maxsend(0x0A, 0x0F)

def loop():
    for i in range(0,2000):
        maxsend(0x04,i%10)
        maxsend(0x03,(i/10)%10)
        maxsend(0x02,(i/100)%10)
        maxsend(0x01,(i/1000)%10)
        time.sleep(0.5)

setup()
loop()
```

When I run it, nothing happen on 7 segment
But it has a message show on terminal:

Only accepts a single tuple as an argument
: Success
Aborted

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Not happen in 7-segment I want to know why?